# How to launch existing Wordpress app image with Docker not at default 80 port?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

may be somebody know how to resolve my issue?

If I use my existing app with wp-content and existing db, every time I've get redirected to the localhost:80 port. How to launch it at another port, maybe 8000 for example?

I have a Wordpress app Dockerfile with next lines:

```
FROM wordpress:latest

COPY ./src /var/www/html

ENV WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD mypass
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_NAME mydb
ENV WORDPRESS_DB_HOST mysql:3306
```

MySQL Dockerfile with existing db dump:

```
FROM mariadb:10.1.20

COPY dump/dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD mypass

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

And docker-compose.yml with that:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    build: mysql/
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: wpapp/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: If you succesfully browse to port 8000, then get redirected to 80...  I would wager this is a wordpress config issue.

Comment: But how to fix that?

Comment: Google wordpress change site url  ;)

Comment: Thanks for a nice advice, but I've already done ofc, that's why am I here with question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the database siteurl and homeurl vales with these lines in you wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:8000/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:8000/');
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you, but for me more comfortable to make it within database because I haven't wp-config in my WP files, I prefer to generate wp-config with environment variables.

Comment: Editing the database means you'll have to do it every time you get a new database dump. You could use an environment variable to define the home and site url in this way. That would remove the need to edit either the database or the wp-config file when running in a new environment.

Comment: Yes, with environment variables it's handy, but anyway I need to have a wp-config.php with getenv() in my src folder when I wont.

Answer (score 2):

After many tests I can recap how to solve this issue.

1. We need to change option_value of 2 rows in db table wp_options with option_names `siteurl` and `home` to `http://localhost:8000` in this case.
2. We need to trigger dockers build to mysql container with volume.

   `docker-compose down -v`

   optional for clean docker cache

   `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`

   `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)`

   `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

   this is not optional ofcourse

   `docker-compose up -d --build`
3. The main thing is to clean browser cache manually, because it invokes redirect faster then cache clean if we use `CMD + R` for example in Safari and it seems like nothing is working after changes.